# "Выспренный" — этимология слова

Tags: этимология

"Выспренный" — значит "вычурный", "замысловатый". Но совершенно не понятно происхождение и корень этого слова. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 10):

Выспренний -  высокопарный, напыщенный,приподнятый, торжественный. Слово исконное. Дается с пометой устаревшее. Однокоренное выспрь - в высоту, в вышину. А как выспрь образовалось? Тут и у Фасмера нет однозначности. Может, от высокъ и перѫ "лечу". А может,  из ст.-слав. въ испрь  от въ и из- + перѫ.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, прилагательное **выспренный** , то есть возвышенный (первоначально без всякой иронии) - прямой родич глагола **воспрянуть**. Воспрянуть духом - подняться над неудачами ; выспренная речь - составленная в высоком стиле, "выламывающаяся" из обыденной речи.
Прянуть - прыгнуть, совершить сильное резкое движение, приставка *вос-/выс-* означает "вверх". Однокоренное слово - распря ( стычка, драка, свара)

Или еще проще - высокий + прение (обсуждение). Человек спорит с оппонентом и начинает приводить все более и более изысканные аргументы, доходит до высочайших примеров ( религиозных, нравственных и тд)

Дополнение. *Выспрь* - вверх, вверху, а также **высота аерная**, то есть атмосфера по-нашему. Высоко + парити = воспарять над землей.
Стянутая основа ПР таит в себе множество подсмыслов, поэтому однозначно ответить невозможно. Парить, переть, выпирать, спорить, прянуть, прение - близкие значения слились в одном слове очень плотно. Превосходный вопрос!